# I am writing a small code in c++ but I keep getting this error

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Tag{
public:
    string name{};
    vector<string> attribute{};
    vector<string> value{};
};

Tag get_tag_and_value(string tag_line){
    Tag tag{};
    for(char c:tag_line){
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
    
    return tag;
}

int main() {
    string temp;
    vector<Tag> tags{};
    
    int N{}, Q{};
    cin>>N>>Q;
    cout<<N<<" "<<Q<<endl;
    for (auto i{0};i<=N;i++){
        getline(cin, temp);
        tags.at(i) = get_tag_and_value(temp);
        temp.erase();
        cout<<temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error I get everytime I run:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

Code works fine when `tags.at(i) = get_tag_and_value(temp);` is not there. What is the problem here?

I expected the code to read the lines and I will process them in `tags.at(i) = get_tag_and_value(temp);`. I tried to read linein `get_tag_and_value()` function but got same error.

Comment: Your vector is empty here:`tags.at(i) = get_tag_and_value(temp);`  so tags.at(i) is out of bounds for any `i`. Change that to `tags.push_back(get_tag_and_value(temp));` or  `tags.emplace_back(get_tag_and_value(temp));`

Answer (score 1):

Your vector has a size of zero, so

```
tags.at(i) = get_tag_and_value(temp);
```

correctly throws an error.

Use this instead

```
tags.push_back(get_tag_and_value(temp));
```

which adds an item to the back of a vector (therefore increasing it's size by one).

It seems to be a common misunderstanding of vectors that they will automatically grow when you assign to a given index. It's not true.